# Calling a function in cesium.js when a event is trigerred

Tags: javascript, html, function, cesiumjs

I have a div created as below

```
<div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
<div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
<div id="toolbar"><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by layout name" onkeydown="search()"/></div>
```

So when enter button is pressed in search box, it should call the function "**Search**".

```
<script id="cesium_sandcastle_script">
function startup(Cesium) {
'use strict';
 var west = 68.0;
 var south = 7.0;
 var east = 89.0;
 var north = 35.0;
 var rectangle = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(west, south, east, north);

 Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 0.5;
 Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = rectangle;
 var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
   timeline: false,
   animation : false,
   vrButton : true,
   selectionIndicator : false
 });


   function search() {
      alert("success");
   }
 }
```

When i run this it is raising an error "**search is not a function**". Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Cesium Sandcastle wraps your code in a `startup` function, as you can see in the first line of JavaScript in your question above, and this shields local declarations from the global scope.  So there's no `window.search` function to bind to.  But binding global functions like this isn't best practice these days.

Give this a try instead:  remove the `onkeydown="search()"` attribute from your HTML code above, and instead subscribe to the event in JavaScript like so:

```
function search() {
    console.log('testing search...');
}

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keypress', search, false);
```